prettier change multi line into single line despite not crossing print width
VS Code 1.92.1
Ubuntu 24.04
Astro based project
Prettier extension installed and set formatter for code-snippets extension as below
.prettierrc file content
printWidth: 140,
  semi: true,
  singleQuote: false,
  tabWidth: 2,
  useTabs: false,
  plugins: ["prettier-plugin-astro", "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss" /* Must come last */],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: "*.astro",
      options: {
        parser: "astro",
      },
      rules: {
        quotes: ["error", "double", { avoidEscape: true }],
      },
    },
  ],

Note: this is working for Astro and normal file also so please do not suggest that the config is wrong
.editorconfig
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

and below is the snippet file from vs code
log.code-snippets

{
  "blog front matter": {
    "scope": "astro, javascript, javascriptreact, typescript, typescriptreact",
    "prefix": "bfm",
    "body": [
      "---",
      "\ntitle: \"\"",
      "\ndescription: ",
      "\npublishDate: ",
      "\ntags: [\"blog\"]",
      "\ndraft: true",
      "\n---",
    ],
    "description": "Creates an element using document.createDocumentFragment"
  }
}

and when save ( Ctrl + S ) this file,
it changed body content in  one line as below
like
 "body": ["---", "\ntitle: \"\"", "\ndescription: ", "\npublishDate: ", "\ntags: [\"blog\"]", "\ndraft: true", "\n---"],

How do we prevent to do it, is there any settings in prettier or what?
Note: if I change default formatter to vsode one then it works as desired;
project.code-workspace
"[snippets]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
        }


but what is missing here?

The issue you’re facing occurs because Prettier formats JSON files according to its default behavior, which attempts to compress arrays when it sees the opportunity, even though you don’t cross the printWidth limit.

Then how to stop this behaviour

@xkeshav, the most reasonable way is to override Prettier formatting for JSON files by changing the default formatter in the VSCode setting, just as you did.
